# how to return the value obtained from fs.readFile in node js?

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

How to possibly, return the data obtained from fread to fwrite callee? Even if I return it, it states the error as "The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Promise" :/

Neither data.then() doesn't works, says data.then() isn't a function

```
const fs=require("fs").promises;
const path=require("path");

async function fread(fn)
{
    try {
        let data=await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,fn),"utf-8")
        return data.data; ***//issue***
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }
}

async function fwrite(from,to)
{
    try {
        const data=fread(from)
     
        await fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,to),data)
       


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }
}

async function fappend(to,data)
{
    try {
        await fs.appendFile(path(__dirname))


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }


}





module.exports={fread,fwrite};
```

Comment: `fread` is `async` so you need to `await const data=fread(from)`.

Comment: omgg thanks alot !!! i was scratching my head over an hour , so basically if we prefix with "await" kw , the promise object gets processed ? or whats the mechanism behind it ? can you provide further more resources ? :D

Comment: Correct. `async/await` is syntactic sugar around Promises, i.e. `then/catch` chains. Allows for traditional sync code flow for async processes.